# Why is gsutil -m cp -R much faster than gsutil cp -R

Tags: google-compute-engine, gsutil

Hi all I am using GCE and now I'm new to bucket. I have tons of pics on my other bucket. I tried copying it as

```
sudo gsutil cp -R dir dir
```

it took me 30 mins still didn't finished the file copy so I tried the suggestion which is to use the -m command

```
sudo gsutil -m cp -R dir dir
```

it was a lot faster. But I wonder what makes it faster. and what does -m stand for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the documentation of [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp):

> If you have a large number of files to upload you might want to use the `gsutil -m` option, to perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy:
>
> `gsutil -m cp -R dir gs://my_bucket'`

So the reason is that the `-m` flag makes the `cp` command open multiple simultaneous requests to copy the files in parallel, therefore speeding up considerably.